# Invalidating session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpsession

When a user has an associated `HttpSession` object and then want to "log out" of the application you would invalidate that `HttpSession` which in turn would remove it from the map that the ServletContext keep of all sessions. But this only removes it on the server side, what happens on the client side? Does the user still keep keep the cookie with the session ID which now no longer has a corresponding session object on the server and keeps sending this to the webserver? And what happens when the user wants to login again after logging out?

Comment: you can invalidate that client side coockies also.

Comment: When the user tries to reconnect the sessionId will not be found so no session will be attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the sessionId cookie will still be kept, but since this sessionId will not match any session object in the server's memory, it will be discarded by the server next time user tries to login again. On the server side it will be quite transparent, request.getSession() will return a new session object automatically.

Comment: Okey, but the old cookie remains until it is invalid?

Comment: It would be down to the browser implementation, but I think the cookie will remain until it is expired in most cases. The expiry time is dictated by your server, like in tomcat's config:

   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   </session-config>

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to the answer of **maksimov**.

Although the cookie is still present on the client side, it is possible for the server to delete the cookie also on the client side. Spring Security does that when a user logs out. Here's the code:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
String cookiePath = //cookie's path
cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The important instruction is `cookie.setMaxAge(0)`. Setting the max age to 0 means the cookie has to be deleted. Thus, the server may ask the client to delete the cookie by sending it the same cookie with a max age of 0.